# How long do chat transcripts last?

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

I was looking at some past transcripts that StackOverflow handles and was wondering if these transcripts ever expire or do they simply live on indefinitely? Do the transcripts go away when the chatroom is closed? I went to the [FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) and didn't find much about it.

Comment: From chat help: "Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users."

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen That tells me nothing regarding the transcripts though. Only the chatrooms.

Comment: Which is why it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chat transcripts live on, even if the room is deleted.

You can find the [oldest deleted rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=created&page=2359&nohide=true) still present on the server, for example, and those that actually had a conversation are still present.

The earliest deleted room with a conversation is the [Google App Engine room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/14) (room id 14), and the transcript is still available today, for example.

Comment: Ah I should have checked that. Thank you for that :)

Comment: ?!? google app engine link **404!**

Comment: Not for me it isn't. Are you logged in?